# Is Validation SSL is directly related to the soap?

Tags: php, ssl, soap

I have the following `PHP` code to communicate with a `Soap WSDL server` From Client:

```
<?php
$url = "https://_SERVER_URL_:8086/erefill_bl/ETIServiceMerchant?wsdl";
$body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:eref="http://erefill.nokia.com">
<soapenv:Header />
 <soapenv:Body>
.
.
.
.
.

 </eref:processRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
'; //VAriable
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"', 
        'Content-Length: '.strlen($body), 
        'Accept: text/xml', 
        'Cache-Control: no-cache', 
        'Pragma: no-cache', 
        'SOAPAction: "processRequest"'
    );
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36");
    // Stuff I have added
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);  
    var_dump(curl_exec($ch));
```

The server administrator Placed a `*.crt` File For Certificate Connection but when I put it connection is lost!

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, realpath('./mycert.crt'));
```

OR When I use Converted `*.pem` File Too.

Only in one case I Connection Established When I Use Following Source Code:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

And I Receive This Response

> The given SOAPAction processRequest does not match an operation.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>The given SOAPAction processRequest does not match an operation.</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Now:
The problem is FOR XML code?

Or
This error occurs because of SSL certification unused?

Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear to be an SSL error since the message relates to SOAP.

Are you connected to the URL specified by the server admin for the SOAP service?

Is processRequest in the WSDL file from the server? Presumably the server is running a SOAP service using the same WSDL file to ensure the interfaces match?

You should also be able to test the SSL with curl from Linux based command line with the curl command, this would clarify whether there are any SSL issues:

```
curl https://_SERVER_URL_:8086/erefill_bl/ETIServiceMerchant?wsdl --verbose --cert ./mycert.crt
```

Comment: `About to connect() to 92.42.**.** port 8086 (#0)
*   Trying 92.42.**.**... connected
* Connected to 92.42.**.** (92.42.**.**) port 8086 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Unable to load client key -8178.
* NSS error -8178
* Closing connection #0
curl: (58) Unable to load client key -8178.
`
This is Curl Response

Comment: Does your crt file contain both certificate and key? It should have both lines like '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----' & '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----'

Comment: No! I have Just a `.crt` File,  And Admin Server Haven't Support ;(

Comment: `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDrDCCApSgAwIB...
MQswCQYDVQQIEw......
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
`
I Have Just a `crt` File By upper Content , Is it enough? Or incomplete information? More...

Comment: Well, we do not know your servers requirements. To use a client certificate with CURLOPT_SSLCERT, AFAIK you also need a key which apparently you do not have. Maybe it is worth clarifying with the server admin, why they gave you a Certificate file with no key. For example, it could also be a CA certificate which would mean you don't need to set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false.

Comment: Thinking about it - it may well be a CA cert. Try replacing `CURLOPT_SSLCERT, realpath('./mycert.crt')`. with `CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath('./mycert.crt')` and set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to true. I'm not sure the XML will work, but the connection should not be lost either.

Comment: Now I have `Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates` Error When i use `CURLOPT_CAINFO`وTnks you for your patience...:)